# SubreportProcessingEventArgs in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, report, rdlc

I have a Dot Net Core project and some RDLC Report in my project.
Now in RDLC report I need a sub report but SubreportProcessingEventArgs not raised. Anybody can help me to how to add a namespace in Dot Net Core to recognize this type of event?

Answer (score 0):

I Tried Hard To Executed Subreports in **Asp MVC .NET Core** . But I Was not Success . I Was Forced Convert SubReports To One Single-level Report .( means : Use DataSet In One Report , Instead Of SubReports In One Report ). **Also** Remember If You Used Charts In RDLC or RDL Report . Asp Core, It Has Error :  **'Assemble Microsoft.Windows.Form Is Not Supported'**.
**My suggestion** Is To Make a Report at Another Class Library(**Old .NET Framework**).Then Call The Created Report Service Project In Asp Core Application.